# Setting MaxBackupIndex and MaxFileSize in logger.xml for Play Framework

Tags: logging, playframework, logback

I'm using Play 2.2.2. I've overridden the default logger.xml by using the command line

```
play debug "~run -Denvironment=%1 -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dlogger.resource=C:\Users\jmatthews\Documents\git\beam-ui\conf\playLoggerConfig-local.xml"
```

This is the contents of playLoggerConfig-local.xml:

```xml
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>c:\tempBeam\server.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

What I need to do is specify a MaxFileSize and MaxBackupIndex so that when server.log gets to a certain size, it backs it up as server.log.1 and starts over and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```xml
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>c:\tempBeam\server.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>server.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- Keeps server.log.X with X from 1 to 5 -->
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <!-- Max file size: 30MB -->
        <maxFileSize>30MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <!-- (...) -->
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Also note that usually `logger.resource` is used to load files present in your classpath (ex: the `conf` directory in your Play project). If this is not the case you should use `logger.file` instead.

Comment: I made those changes and started the project in Play and got the following error: `09:45:06,842 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:79 - no applicable action for [rollingPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy]]` and four others regarding fileNamePattern, minIndex, maxIndex, and triggeringPolicy

Comment: I made this update `<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">` and it launches without errors but I'm not seeing the expected behaviour. When the log file reaches the MaxFileSize, it continues writing to the same log file beyond that size.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logback-documentation for RollingFileAppender [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender)

May be you need to add an encoder:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %m%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```